# Acer Aspire One Ubuntu 14.04 Installing on flash drive instead of computer

Tags: flash, acer, drive, aspire

I'm trying to install ubuntu 14.04 onto my father's computer. I've tried it quite often but almost every time I get the live flash drive made and install it, it only boots with the flash drive in the usb port, in other words I feel like it's just installing onto the flash drive rather than the Hard drive itself. I'm pressed for time and kind of scared :/
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: How are you making partitions? Make sure mount / partition in your HDD (maybe SSD) and not your usb.

Comment: Honestly I'm not entirely sure about how exactly partitions work. I 'm not really sure what mount is either. Is that something I can change in the boot menu?

Comment: After installing it on the hard drive, did you remove the USB drive? There shouldn't be any question about what Ubuntu is installed on if the computer boots without the flash drive...

Comment: It didn't boot without the flash drive. I did some more research and I think it has something to do with RAID (Honestly I don't know what that is) and am just going to reinstall Windows 7. Hopefully this goes more smoothly. Thanks for taking the time to comment though. I appreciate it.

Comment: I would advise you to see the link:http://www.wikihow.com/Install-Ubuntu-Linux There's a nice tutorial.